# Powershell exporting variables to excel

Tags: excel, powershell

Ok, so I've been given the task of learning powershell at work to write a few scripts. I have some experience with other languages (just a little) like Java, Python, HTML, and CSS. Powershell is turning out to be a totally different beast, and so I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing things sometimes. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to get my computer name, domain, username and datetime into an excel doc. Here's what I'm trying:

```
$compname = $env:COMPUTERNAME | Select-Object @{Name='Computer Name'; Expression={$_.Computer_Name}}
$domain = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN | Select-Object @{Name='Domain'; Expression={$_.Domain}}
$user = $env:USERNAME | Select-Object @{Name='Username'; Expression={$_.Username}}
$date = Get-Date -format F | Select-Object @{Name='Date'; Expression={$_}}
$file = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\test4.csv" 
$row = @($Date, $compname, $domain, $user)
$row | Export-Csv $file -NoType
```

I put my variables into an array hoping it would help, but no luck. Right now only the date is printing. The other variables are all empty and I have no idea why. I can get them to work using Write-Out, but not exactly the way I want, and I'm assuming that Export-CSV is my best option. Am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: The `$env:*` variables don't have individual named properties, they are just strings. Use `$_` inside the Expression instead of `$_.Name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pipe an array or a collection of objects (`@(1,2,3)` is 3-element array for example), `Export-Csv` treats each object as a separate row.

If you want all the values in different columns on the same row, you'll need to create an object with the properties you want in each column.

You can create a custom object with the `New-Object` cmdlet and its `-Property` parameter. Assign the properties to a hashtable and use that as the `Property` argument, like so:

```
$Props = @{
    "Date" = Get-Date -Format f
    "Computer Name" = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    "Username" = $env:USERNAME
    "Domain" = $env:USERDNSDOMAIN
}

$MyObject = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Props
```

Now, you can pipe the object to `Export-Csv`:

```
$FilePath = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\test4.csv" 

$MyObject | Export-Csv $FilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

If you want to change the order of the columns (or remove or add new ones on the fly), you can use `Select-Object`:

```
$MyObject | Select-Object 'Date','Domain','Username','Computer Name' | Export-Csv $FilePath -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: So in that first snippet, are you adding properties to $Props? I thought that was adding other variables to it as an array?

Comment: Ok, that does exactly what I was looking for, thanks! There's so many different things to learn in powershell, I'm having trouble knowing what to even look for.